# Fetch all lines above the first match string using regex101

Tags: regex

I have the below sql

```
    select 
    a,
    b,c
    from (
                select a,b,
                       c,d
                from 
                table1
            )
where c=1234
```

I need to fetch the column names from the outer most select using regex101.

Output should be

```
a,
b,c
```

I tried using sed and able to achieve it. `sed -n '/from/q;p'`. However, I need to use regex to achieve this. I tried in regex101 server, but not able to achieve.

https://regex101.com/r/VKXUe5/1

Could you please help ? Any language in regex101 is fine.

Comment: What language are you using to apply a RegExp/what flavor of RegExp are you working with? Please edit your question to tag it as such.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/VKXUe5/2

Comment: @esqew - Updated the question as you suggested. Any language given in regex101 is fine

Comment: Your sed command just extracts the first line with `from` text in it. It is equal to `.*from.*` regex. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/SObiBZ/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're language-agnostic, the following JavaScript solution should suffice given your current requirements. I've added a bit of additional string processing to get to your desired end state regarding the whitespace (as defined in your initial question). This is likely not the fastest or most elegant solution, but should meet your needs:

```js
const pattern = /(?<=^select\s+)(?<fields>.*?)(?=from)/si;
const query = `select 
    a,
    b,c
    from (
                select a,b,
                       c,d
                from 
                table1
            )
where c=1234`;

const matches = query.match(pattern);
console.log(matches.groups.fields.trim().split('\n').map(cv => cv.trim()).join('\n'));
```